# WPF RenderTargetBitmap of an Items Panel but omit certain elements

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using RenderTargetBitmap.Render(panel) to take a snap of an items panel.

However I want to omit certain elements (custom items with say OmitWhileRenderingToBitmap property set to false).

Is there some easy way of doing this short of removing the items from the items panel, taking the snap and then adding them back?

Edit: Essentially this is the key bit in my custom listbox class. Remove the filter bits and everything works as expected.

```
    protected void UpdatePanelBitmapSource()
    {
        if (this._itemsPanel != null) //_itemsPanel here is the canvas within the ListBox. Not rendering the ListBox for a reason.
        {
            Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this._itemsPanel).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

            var existingFilter = this.Items.Filter;

            // Add filter
            this.Items.Filter = item =>
            {
                var mgvListBoxItem = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as MGVListBoxItem;

                if (mgvListBoxItem != null)
                    return !mgvListBoxItem.IsEditable;
                else
                    return false;
            };

            var panelBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                (int)Math.Floor(this._itemsPanel.ActualWidth),
                (int)Math.Floor(this._itemsPanel.ActualHeight),
                m.M11 * 96.0,
                m.M22 * 96.0,
                PixelFormats.Default);
            panelBitmap.Render(this._itemsPanel);

            // Remove filter
            this.Items.Filter = existingFilter;

            this.PanelBitmapSource = panelBitmap;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did something like this

```
        protected void OnUpdatePanelBitmapSource()
    {
        if (this._itemsPanel != null)
        {
            Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this._itemsPanel).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

            var hiddenItems = new List<MGVListBoxItem>();

            foreach(var item in this.Items)
            {
                var mgvListBoxItem = this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as MGVListBoxItem;
                if (mgvListBoxItem != null && mgvListBoxItem.IsEditable && mgvListBoxItem.IsVisible)
                {
                    mgvListBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    hiddenItems.Add(mgvListBoxItem);
                }
            }

            var panelBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                (int)Math.Floor(this._itemsPanel.ActualWidth),
                (int)Math.Floor(this._itemsPanel.ActualHeight),
                m.M11 * 96.0,
                m.M22 * 96.0,
                PixelFormats.Default);

            panelBitmap.Render(this._itemsPanel);

            foreach (var mgvListBoxItem in hiddenItems)
            {
                mgvListBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            this.PanelBitmapSource = panelBitmap;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just apply a filter:

```
// Add filter
yourItemsControl.Items.Filter = o =>
    {
        YourType item = (YourType)o;
        return !item.OmitWhileRenderingToBitmap;
    };


// Render to bitmap
// ...

// Remove filter
yourItemsControl.Items.Filter = null;
```

Comment: Am not sure why but this doesn't work. I add a couple of items with the omit flag on for one and off for another. I can see in the debugger that its all fine. But all it renders is the ItemsControl background and no items. Any thoughts?

Comment: Even stranger, the filter does apply to the items control, but the rendered image has no items in it.

Comment: @NVM, I just looked at the code, I can see anything obviously wrong... Did you try to execute step by step to see what's happening? You can put a breakpoint inside the filter lambda expression

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it makes sense to access the ItemContainer from the filter... the containers are probably not generated yet, since the ItemsControl doesn't know yet if it must display them

Comment: Hmm. Well everything is as expected when stepping through the debugger. I can get to the itemcontainers as well. I can also see the omit flag on in some items and off in others.

Comment: I dont want to use the items directly because the list box is a custom control and I dont want references to VM code in that.